# How to capture enter key press for select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 dropdown for countries (multiselect). When user types keywords, it shows the related items in the menu.
For e.g., if user types *ind*, the menu shows *India* and *Indonesia*.
If the enter key is pressed, the first item (*India*) is selected. This is the default behavior.

Now, I would like to select both the countries when user types *ind* and presses enter.

```
$(".select2-search__field").on("keyup",  function (e) { 
    console.log(e.keyCode);       
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert();
    }
});
```

With the above code, the console logs show up for *i*, *n* & *d* but not for the *Enter key*, and hence the alert never shows.
I guess the default select2 behavior is preventing my code to be triggered.

What should I do, so that I can capture the enter key press.

https://jsfiddle.net/bwp0svq6/1/

Comment: can you create demo showing the OP?

Comment: @guradio I have added the link to the fiddle. Please have a look.

Comment: @guradio. It's not working. Updated your fiddle with a log. pls check.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/68tovszd/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keypress event has been deprecated. You may want to use `keydown` instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').select2();

  $(".select2-search__field").on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      alert();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
  <option value="1">Argentina</option>
  <option value="2">Brazil</option>
  <option value="3">China</option>
  <option value="4">India</option>
  <option value="5">Indonesia</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just FYI, `keypress` has not been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to replace '-' dash with nothing as I typed. I had to wait for the select2 items to initialise, as follows:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $(".select2-input").on("keyup", function (e) {
                //console.log('key pressed');
                var el = $(e.target);
                $(el).val($(el).val().replace('-', ''));//remove dashes
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    alert('enter key');
                }
            });
        },500);
    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use this code to check as there can be a mouse click :

```js
   

$('#example').select2();

$("#example").on("click change keydown", function (e) { 
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);       
        if (keycode == 13) {
            console.log('inside')
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="1">Argentina</option>
    <option value="2">Brazil</option>
    <option value="3">China</option>
    <option value="4">India</option>
    <option value="5">Indonesia</option>    
</select>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you pls explain what this does. Will this UI not have a textbox to type. If so, then cant use. Also, if user clicks on India and it selects India & Indonesia, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh no nothing like that, its just that you are using multiselect with somelibrary but i am not. its not gonna change your functionality and UI. Just simply use your select id with my jquery code and you are all set to work.e.g. $('#here_your_id_of_select')

Comment: "using multiselect with somelibrary". Thats the whole point. Select2 library should be used, and should only capture enter press. Your code didnt work for me. Could you pls try it in my fiddle and check.